# Is it possible to bulk rename different Google Docs with different document names?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-chrome-extension, google-drive-api, google-docs

To summarize, I want to give my students a doc named something like "Student A - Biology Report - Sem 2" to work on (the "Student A" part replaced with each student's name).
I thought of asking the students to do it, but no matter how many instructions you give them, there are always a few who don't follow those.
Doing it manually for each student in a batch of 70 is going to be a task.

On this forum I found a script that lets me bulk copy documents within seconds, and that helped immensely.
Is there a way for me to do the renaming quickly using a script or any other tool? (note that these will be Google Docs only)

Comment: If you need only an answer of yes or no, I think that the answer to your question of `Is there a way for me to do the renaming quickly using a script or any other tool?` is yes. But, from your question, I cannot imagine your concrete situation. So, unfortunately, I cannot propose a sample script. I apologize for my poor English skill.